# how to apply random.choice to my customized class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading *Fluent Python*.

Code 1-1, here it constructs a class with namedtuples and implements `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])


class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for rank in self.ranks for suit in self.suits]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

but later the author uses random.choice to choose a card from deck

```
from random import choice
deck = FrenchDeck()
choice(deck)
```

how is this working? I don't think deck is a sequence.

Comment: Python uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): By giving your type a length and a way to access an item at an index, you *made* it [a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). So yes, `deck` is a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `__getitem__` makes your class iterable. Watch:

```
>>> class LegacyIterable(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return self._list[item]
... 
>>> x = LegacyIterable()
>>> for e in x:
...     print e
... 
a
b
c
```

If a class does not have an `__iter__` method but a `__getitem__` method, Python, when forced to do so, constructs an iterator from an instance that tries to access its elements via `__getitem__`. It starts at index 0 and ends as soon as an `IndexError` is thrown.

However, since `LegacyIterable` instances don't have a `__len__` method, they formally don't count as sequences yet and `random.choice` would complain with

```
TypeError: object of type 'LegacyIterable' has no len()
```

However, once we give it a `__len__` method instances count as sequences, and that's all that `random.choice` wants according to its documentation.

```
>>> LegacyIterable.__len__ = lambda x: 3
>>> choice(LegacyIterable())
'c'
```

> choice(self, seq) method of random.Random instance
>       Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice` takes a random element from a non-empty *sequence*. If you implement `__getitem__`, [python can use that to treat your object as a sequence by indexing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#iter) and that's what it does.

Answer (score 0):

`deck` is indeed not a list, **but** as stated by [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), any object whose class implements `__getitem__` can be treated as a list-like object, e.g. *a sequence*. Since implementing `__getitem__` allows you things like `deck[i]`, you can call `choice(deck)` because what `choice(deck)` does is it generates a random number `i` betwen 0 and `len(deck)` and returns `deck(i)`.

Comment: Yes, wrong word used. I wanted to use list instead of sequence. Will correct my mistake, didn't even see it...